# How can I amend a non-HEAD commit with Git?

Tags: git

I've committed a series of changes to a local topic branch in my Git repository. After each commit, I run a small set of smoke tests to verify the functionality, when possible. Upon running a larger set of tests later before submitting a pull request, I discover some more bugs missed earlier. I could create a new commit for the bug fixes but since it's just a local topic branch I'd like to modify the commits that I already have. There's two ways that I've been doing it:

1. Make the changes, test them. Stash them and then pop at the appropriate point during rebase -i.
2. Make a new commit then rebase -i to reorder them and squash it.

If the bug fix happened to be needed in the last commit, then I can commit with --amend to solve the problem. Does Git provide a shortcut to amending parents of HEAD or am I stuck with the current method?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is another way to approach this problem, which is to use [TopGit](http://github.com/greenrd/topgit) in the following way: Each commit in your topic branch would instead become its own branch (you can use `tg import` for this when the commits already exist). To edit a commit, you would just switch to its corresponding branch, edit it, `git commit` it, and then run `tg update -a` to ripple the changes forward to all the patches that depended on it. Finally, you would run `tg export` (selecting the appropriate command-line options) to convert your temporary TopGit branches into the final series of revisions.

Comment: Very cool - looks like it would sure solve my problem. Thanks!

Answer (score 5):

Git does not provide shortcuts for amending commits other than the current HEAD. This is because *every change* of a commit will effectively create a completely new commit object which is incompatible with the one before. That also means that when you were to change the direct parent of HEAD, then HEAD would need to change too. This is not obvious and a destructive action. It’s also very discouraged to edit any commit you have published before.

If you really want to do that, you will have to do an interactive rebase, where the impact is made very clear: Every rebase will create new, incompatible commit objects.

The correct solution would be to keep the history intact as it is, even if there is an error and simply add a new commit which fixes the bug introduced earlier. Git is supposed to respect the history as it was in the project. Just as you identified and fixed that bug actually later, you should also create a commit where you fix that bug later. There is nothing wrong with having non-perfect code as the part of the history. Constantly changing commits from the past would just introduce more problems that you solve with it and is somewhat against the “spirit of source control”.

Comment: I like to think of topic branches as stories which can be edited as will. It helps to make the history more readable by pruning the greatest churn in changes and it helps reduce work in code review. I agree, though, that once merged rewriting history becomes unattractive.

Answer (score 3):

You said `local branch` and I'm going to answer assuming you didn't push any thing yet, otherwise don't do this.

Assuming the commit you want to edit is 'abcdef' you'll run a rebase

```
git rebase abcdef~ 
# the ~ is needed, you need the parent of the commit you want to edit
```

Then when your editor starts up, change the commit you want to edit from `pick` to `edit` or `e`, save and close and the `HEAD` will stop in that place, do whatever changes you want and stage them then do a `commit` or `rebase --continue`  and the rebase will continue.

Comment: Wait, do you mean `abcdef^`?  I thought `~` always has to take a number, e.g. `abcdef~1`

Comment: That's what I'm doing already (#2). Wanted to know if there was a shortcut. My repository is very large and while not unteneable, there's value to avoiding the time for these operations (a few minutes typically).

Comment: `~` without a number means one parent up, just like `^`

Comment: If that's what you are doing then you are doing it the best way I know of, there's no amend for parents further up the tree